# Adding Search Functionality To My Apps Android

Tags: android, search

I want to add search functionality into my apps, and also I did some research (http://developer.android.com/training/search/index.html) but I don't want to use database/sql. I want it to be something like this (http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-adding-search-functionality-to-listview/) where you put all your search terms in a list of strings.
Question:
How do I implement the function where you click one of those search terms in listview, and the strings of the search term clicked will show up. Or is there any alternative way I can do this?
Comments are appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Probably this might help you..[see here](http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2013/04/implementing-search-functionality.html)
I think you should implement a new adapter rather than using ArrayAdapter. I don't know whether it is possible to do that using ArrayAdapter also.